# I want train_test_split to train mainly on one specific number range

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, jupyter

I am running some regression models in jupyter/python to predict the cycle time of certain projects. I used train_test_split from sklearn to randomly divide my data set.

The models tend to work pretty well for projects with high cycle times (between 150 - 300 days), but I care more about the lower cycle times between 0 and 50 days.

I believe the model is more accurate for the higher range because most of the projects (about 60-70%) have cycle times over 100 days. I want my model to mainly get the lower cycle times right, because for the purposes of what I'm doing, a project with a cycle time of 120 days is the same as a project with 300 day cycle time.

In my mind, I need to train more on the projects with shorter cycle times? I feel like this might help?

1. Is there a way to split the data less randomly? Aka train on a higher ratio of shorter cycle time projects
2. Is there a better or different approach I should consider?